# Confidence in face recognition using Fisher faces

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, face-recognition, lda

I am trying to build a face recognizer using fisher faces in OpenCV.

```
model->predict(face,prediction,confidence);
```

This is the line that predicts a face with an associated confidence. Intuitively confidence is the distance parameter used in matching. I tried digging into the "facerec.cpp" file within the OpenCV library which provides implementation of the model.But I didnt find much details on how confidence is calculated.

Please provide an explanation on how confidence is calculated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: yes, that's the distance between your test-image and the closest from the database, so : less==better.

Comment: @berak Can you tell how it's calculated? Is short,whats the math behind it?

Comment: a simple nearest-neighbour search, L2 norm. (eucl.distance) for fisher and eigenfaces, chi-square norm for lbp-histograms.

Comment: @berak Where is it implemented within opencv source code?Would like to dig deeper into it

Comment: just look at the final lines in the resp. predict methods.

Comment: @berak So,in the run time of my recognizer, confidence tells me the distance from nearest database match.  but if I vary my training data then correspondingly confidence of newer run time prediction also changes right? Can I manually tweak an equation for confidence so that regardless of my training data I can decide a range of confidence value that leads to true recognition?

Comment: not really, due to the nature of this. all you can do is estimate a good threshold value by doing a lot of tests against a given trainset (and ofc. test again, once your traindata changes)

Comment: ok.,that looks infeasible. Because I have no clue how an end user is going to train it with.
Thanks for the help @berak